# Find position and normal of plane tangental to the intersection of 2 spheres

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, intersection

Given a set of 2 spheres, how can one find the plane tangental to the intersection point of the spheres?

Suppose I have the following input

```
Vector3 sphere1 = new Vector3(8, 6, 2);
float radius1 = 5f;

Vector3 sphere2 = new Vector3(5, 3, 8);
float radius2 = 8f;
```

How can I get the following outpout:

```
Vector3 planePosition;
Vector3 planeNormal;
```

Most solutions I found online use linear algebra jargon that I find hard to understand and put some code functions behind. I'd appreciate it if someone could try to help me  out

Comment: I think, most general case, intersection of 2 spherical surfaces shapes a circle. What is the really wanted? Can you show with figure?

Comment: I'd like to calculate the intersection point of 4 spheres, a proposed method I found online is to subtract the sphere equations from another, resulting in 3 different planes that could intersect at some point. I just dont know how to achieve that, I know that the normal is found by sqrt((dot(point 1 - point2)), but I dont know how to find the point of intersection